# Accessing Windows Service Startup or Shutdown Progress Values

Tags: c#, winapi, .net-4.0, windows-services

I want start or stop any service and poll `dwCheckPoint` of `SERVICE_STATUS`, and use it to populate a Progress Bar. Or use any other way to access the progress value that you see for example in the services control panel.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `SERVICE_STATUS` seems to imply that services populate these values and so therefore perhaps they can be accessed. The progress bar shown in the services control panel "jumps" for some services, indicating an integer is being set by the service and read by the monitoring application.

### dwCheckPoint

The check-point value the service increments periodically to report its progress during a lengthy start, stop, pause, or continue operation. For example, the service should increment this value as it completes each step of its initialization when it is starting up. *The user interface program that invoked the operation on the service uses this value to track the progress of the service during a lengthy operation.* This value is not valid and should be zero when the service does not have a start, stop, pause, or continue operation pending.

### dwWaitHint

The estimated time required for a pending start, stop, pause, or continue operation, in milliseconds. Before the specified amount of time has elapsed, the service should make its next call to the SetServiceStatus function with either an incremented dwCheckPoint value or a change in dwCurrentState. If the amount of time specified by dwWaitHint passes, and dwCheckPoint has not been incremented or dwCurrentState has not changed, the service control manager or service control program can assume that an error has occurred and the service should be stopped. However, if the service shares a process with other services, the service control manager cannot terminate the service application because it would have to terminate the other services sharing the process as well.

Any examples of this?

Comment: I hate to tell you this but the progress bar in service control panel is a lie... there's not progress behind it except for at best when a service requests more time to shut down, but even then I don't think it honors that. I would just show an indeterminate style progress bar

The bar just kind of moves upward.

Comment: @Darren Kopp, `dwCheckPoint` is giving data. Are you saying the `dwCheckPoint` data does not come from within Sql Server itself as the documentation for it suggests? If that is what you are saying, what is the url that documents that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a partial answer. I can get the progress; the maximum progress can also be tracked over time. I'm still looking for the best way to tweak it. It's feasible now; I'm looking to make it perfect...
any ideas would be appreciated. That's why I'm not marking my own answer yet.

[image]
*Simple Demo*

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DeveloperWorkbench.UI
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.ProgressChanged += Service_ProgressChanged;
            this.MaxProgressChanged += Service_MaxProgressChanged;
        }

        private delegate void IntDelegate(int value);

        private event IntDelegate ProgressChanged;
        private event IntDelegate MaxProgressChanged;

        private void Service_ProgressChanged(int value)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new IntDelegate(Service_ProgressChanged), value);
            else
            {
                lblProgress.Text = value.ToString();
                progressBar1.Value = value;
            }
        }

        private void Service_MaxProgressChanged(int value)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new IntDelegate(Service_MaxProgressChanged), value);
            else
            {
                progressBar1.Maximum = value;
            }            
        }

        private void UpdateServiceProgress(ServiceController serviceController)
        {
            int progress = 0;
            var maxProgressList = new List<int>(){119,120,744,745, 746};
            int maxProgressIndex = 0;
            int maxProgress = 747;
            bool tripped =  false;

            MaxProgressChanged(maxProgress);
            try
            {
                IntPtr smHandle = NativeMethods.OpenSCManager(null, null, NativeMethods.ServiceAccess.ENUMERATE_SERVICE);
                if (smHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    IntPtr svHandle = NativeMethods.OpenService(smHandle, serviceController.ServiceName, NativeMethods.ServiceAccess.ENUMERATE_SERVICE);
                    if (svHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        var servStat = new NativeMethods.SERVICE_STATUS();
                        while (servStat.dwCurrentState != NativeMethods.ServiceState.Running)
                        {
                            if (NativeMethods.QueryServiceStatus(svHandle, servStat))
                            {
                                progress += servStat.dwCheckPoint;
                                if (progress > maxProgress)
                                {
                                    maxProgressIndex++;
                                    if (maxProgressIndex < maxProgressList.Count)
                                    {
                                        maxProgress = maxProgressList[maxProgressIndex];
                                        MaxProgressChanged(maxProgress);
                                    }
                                    else
                                        tripped = true;
                                }

                                ProgressChanged(progress);
                            }

                        }

                        NativeMethods.CloseServiceHandle(svHandle);
                    }
                    NativeMethods.CloseServiceHandle(smHandle);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

            }
            if (tripped)
            {
                maxProgressList.Add(progress);
                Console.WriteLine("max progress {0}", progress);
            }

        }

        public static class NativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("AdvApi32")]
            public static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string machineName, string databaseName, ServiceAccess access);
            [DllImport("AdvApi32")]
            public static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr serviceManagerHandle, string serviceName, ServiceAccess access);
            [DllImport("AdvApi32")]
            public static extern bool CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr serviceHandle);
            [DllImport("AdvApi32")]
            public static extern bool QueryServiceStatus(IntPtr serviceHandle, [Out] SERVICE_STATUS status);

            [Flags]
            public enum ServiceAccess : uint
            {
                ALL_ACCESS = 0xF003F,
                CREATE_SERVICE = 0x2,
                CONNECT = 0x1,
                ENUMERATE_SERVICE = 0x4,
                LOCK = 0x8,
                MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG = 0x20,
                QUERY_LOCK_STATUS = 0x10,
                GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000,
                GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000,
                GENERIC_EXECUTE = 0x20000000,
                GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000
            }

            public enum ServiceState
            {
                Stopped = 1,
                StopPending = 3,
                StartPending = 2,
                Running = 4,
                Paused = 7,
                PausePending = 6,
                ContinuePending = 5
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
            public class SERVICE_STATUS
            {
                public int dwServiceType;
                public ServiceState dwCurrentState;
                public int dwControlsAccepted;
                public int dwWin32ExitCode;
                public int dwServiceSpecificExitCode;
                public int dwCheckPoint;
                public int dwWaitHint;
            };
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 0;

            var service = new ServiceController("MSSQLSERVER");
            if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                service.Stop(); 
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
            }
            service.Start();
            var task = new Task(() => UpdateServiceProgress(service));
            task.Start();
        }

    }
}
```

And the form designer code:

```
namespace DeveloperWorkbench.UI
{
    partial class Form2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form2));
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.progressBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
            this.lblProgress = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(207, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "Start Sql Server";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // progressBar1
            // 
            this.progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 42);
            this.progressBar1.Name = "progressBar1";
            this.progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(207, 23);
            this.progressBar1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // lblProgress
            // 
            this.lblProgress.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblProgress.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(227, 22);
            this.lblProgress.Name = "lblProgress";
            this.lblProgress.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
            this.lblProgress.TabIndex = 2;
            this.lblProgress.Text = "label1";
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(303, 74);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblProgress);
            this.Controls.Add(this.progressBar1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Text = "Service Status";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progressBar1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblProgress;
    }
}
```